# Dockerfile: best way to run a local installer script?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Yocto Linux toolchain installer script `toolchain.sh`. If I run this, it installs a bunch of cross compilers to `/opt`. What's the best way I can do this for a pre-made docker image? So far I've done this:

```
ADD ./toolchain.sh /opt
RUN yes | /opt/toolchain.sh
RUN rm -f /opt/toolchain.sh
```

This seems to work, but it seems inefficient because now my image has both the installer and the unpackaged toolchain taking up more space.

Is there a way to do this without taking up unnecessary space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit your layers:

```
ADD ./toolchain.sh /opt

RUN yes | /opt/toolchain.sh && \
  rm -f /opt/toolchain.sh
```

This ensures, you do not create an extra layer for the toolchain.sh, since you will remove it, it just creates extra size for your docker image.

If you are curious, that is why people do not use several run-statements in dockerfiles, but rather create huge "one liners" with `&& \` and try to separate them for better readability.

Other then that, what you do is perfectly valid and designed for docker - nothing to worry about.